# Добавить в таблицу строки, которых нет в другой таблице

Tags: sql, sql-server

Подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощью sql запроса вставить в одну таблицу данные из другой подобной таблицы, которых нет в первой таблице.

В приведённом ниже запросе работает всё, кроме INSERT. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой должен быть запрос INSERT, чтоб после его выполнения в таблице @t1 появилось 3 строки со значениями "ms", "sec" и "min"?

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.type1 AS TABLE
(
  Id BIGINT IDENTITY,
  TypeId BIGINT NOT NULL
  ,[Order] INT NOT NULL
  ,Val NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)

  WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)

CREATE TYPE dbo.type2 AS TABLE
(
  TypeId BIGINT NOT NULL
  ,[Order] INT NOT NULL
  ,Val NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
)
DECLARE @t1 dbo.type1;
INSERT INTO @t1 (TypeId, [Order], Val)
  VALUES (9, 1, 'ms'), (9, 2, 'sec');
DECLARE @t2 dbo.type2;
INSERT INTO @t2 (TypeId, [Order], Val)
  VALUES (9, 2, 'sec'), (9, 3, 'min');
SELECT * FROM @t1;
SELECT * FROM @t2;

/*?????????*/
INSERT INTO @t1 SELECT * FROM @t2 WHERE @t1.TypeId != @t2.TypeId OR @t1.[Order] != @t2.[Order] OR @t1.Val != @t2.Val;

SELECT * FROM @t1;
```

Comment: Используйте MERGE с единственной секцией WHEN NOT MATCHED.

Comment: @Akina , да, этот вариант сработал, только пришлось условие переделать
      MERGE INTO '@'t1 t1
      USING (SELECT TypeId, [Order], Val FROM '@'t2) t2
      ON (t1.TypeId = t2.TypeId AND t1.[Order] = t2.[Order] AND t1.Val = t2.Val)
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (TypeId, [Order], Val) VALUES (t2.TypeId, t2.[Order], t2.Val);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO @t1 
SELECT TypeId, [Order], Val FROM @t2
EXCEPT 
SELECT TypeId, [Order], Val FROM @t1
```

Если нужно другие столбцы

```
WITH diff as (
  SELECT TypeId, [Order], Val FROM @t2
  EXCEPT 
  SELECT TypeId, [Order], Val FROM @t1)
INSERT INTO @t1
    SELECT d.TypeId, d.[Order], d.Val --сюда остальные столбцы 
    FROM diff d
    JOIN @t2 t ON d.TypeId = t.TypeId AND d.[Order] = t.[Order] ANd d.Val = t.Val;
```

Comment: чудо свершилось - благодарю!

Comment: добавил в таблицы новый столбец DescId BIGINT и появилась проблема - требуется указывать этот столбец после EXCEPT, что также влияет на результат выборки. А мне не нужно, чтоб это столбец влиял на результат. Как-то можно исключить этот столбец из условия выборки EXCEPT?

Comment: есть же выше вариант через MERGE, этот тоже можно переделать с использованием CTE, например, но он будет длиннее варианта с MERGE

Comment: добавил вариант с CTE

Comment: да, с MERGE у меня сработало. Благодарю за ответ